# How to execute long blocking operations in vert.x?

Tags: vert.x

The [Vext.x Core Manual](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/) advises to execute blocking code using `executeBlocking()` to prevent the Event Loop from being blocked. Nevertheless, it also states:

> Blocking code [in `executeBlocking`] should block for a reasonable amount of time (i.e no more than a few seconds). Long blocking operations ... are precluded. When the blocking operation lasts more than the 10 seconds, a message will be printed on the console [...]. **Long blocking operations should use a dedicated thread managed by the application, which can interact with verticles using the event-bus or runOnContext**

So I cannot execute long blocking operations in `executeBlocking`.

To illustrate the point, say, for example, I'm reading waiting for an infinite data stream, such as keyboard keys being pressed. Every time new data arrives (a key being pressed) I want to dispatch an event to the event bus.

```java
while(keyboard.hasNextByte()) { // loops forever
  eventBus.publish("keyboard.keypress", keyboard.nextByte());
}
```

As I understand it, creating your own threads would defeat Vert.x' design. So how can execute such indefinitely blocking code without using `executeBlocking`?

Comment: I'd put the `while(true){}` op in another process (a verticle?) so it sends something over event bus while running for ever w/o blocking

Comment: @injecteer Moving the loop to another verticle will not prevent it from blocking the Event Bus thread. Am I understanding you right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is really a problem with the idea of creating a separate thread "managed by the application".
And in your case, this thread would be very simple, basically, start it when the application starts, and that's it.